# How to show Firebase data only once?

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an android app which uses Firebase Realtime database.
This app is quite similar like a social media app with limited functionality.
The app will show the post contain text data to the users.
I'm stuck with the two problem in which I solved the first one with the help of Pagination but couldn't able to solve the second .
The problem is How can I identify if the post is already seen by the other users and then not show it again. 
like other social media platforms 
For example Quora, Quora will show different answer every time we open the app.
Do I need to remap my data get this functionality ?
My user object and post object will look something like this.

```
   User{ 
      Name;
      Id;
      Post;
   }

Post {
    dateCreated;
    data;
    userId;
}
```

My database tree structure will look something like this

```
       ROOT
      /    \
   POST    Users
```

I'm keeping the copy of the post in child node of ROOT that is POST and also in every users node to get the post posted by the user.
PS: sorry for the poor English.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to

1- Show posts with NO views yet, you can filter posts where for example `num_reads < 3`. The `num_reads` will be increased everytime a user sees the post.

2- Show posts to use which the user himself didn't read yet. In this case it is better to create a collection `user_post_read` which will be many-to-many (ie. link user to post read). Get all posts where the is no entry for current user in `user_post_read`

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more. I didn't get it.

Comment: @timph What do you want to do? Show posts with NO views yet (from anybody), or show posts which current user didn't view yet ?

Comment: The later one. I want to show only once like instagram seach feed does. or the way dating app works. they only the post only once. How can I achieve that

Comment: AFAIK, for firebase, create a collection that holds whether every user read every message. When a new message is added, add the message id to that collection, with every user as not read yet. This will give you much speed, but large space will be needed also. If you don't care about speed but you care about space, you can store messages ids the user has read in his record. Then you search for messages that do not added in user messages he has read

Comment: I'm still not getting the your point
Here is the situation suppose there are 10 users and out of them one posted the post from now how can I keep track of the post and how I'll know that the post is not seen by few people so that I can show them.

Comment: for example: `posts: [{id: 1, text: 'test test'}, {id: 2, text: 'test1 test1'}]` add a new collection => `post_user: [{msg_id: 1, user_id: 1, read: false}, {msg_id: 1, user_id: 2, read: false}, {msg_id: 2, user_id: 1, read: false}, {msg_id: 2, user_id: 2, read: false}]`